# How to change an attribute in the newly created VIEW in mysql?

Tags: mysql, rename

So I have created a view and want to display new columns of the view with new names, for instance:

```
CREATE VIEW monthly_view AS
(SELECT co.object_id, co.object_alias, cm.method_alias, dr.data_value,
           cd.data_uom, dr.date_timestamp, dr.delay_value, dr.delay_pct
FROM data_realtime AS dr
JOIN chroniker_object AS co ON co.object_id=dr.object_id
JOIN chroniker_data AS cd ON cd.data_id=dr.data_id
JOIN chroniker_method AS cm ON cm.method_id=co.method_id)
```

What i want is whenever "monthly_view" is displayed, the "co.object_id" can be shows as "Object".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alias:

```
CREATE VIEW monthly_view AS
SELECT co.object_id AS Object,
       co.object_alias AS ...,
       cm.method_alias AS ...,
       ...
FROM
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select co.object_id AS object, ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving aliases in select statement?

```
CREATE VIEW monthly_view AS
(SELECT co.object_id AS Object, 
        co.object_alias AS ObjectAlias, 
        ....
FROM data_realtime AS dr
JOIN chroniker_object AS co ON co.object_id=dr.object_id
JOIN chroniker_data AS cd ON cd.data_id=dr.data_id
JOIN chroniker_method AS cm ON cm.method_id=co.method_id)
```